# How to create a TextBox like RichTextBox in WinCE 5.0 OS (C#)?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, windows-ce, rtf

Now I have the following ideas:
  1.override TextBox's OnPaint Event,use Graphics to draw rich string-font;
  2.use RTF to save and display the rich format.

But I do not know which method is better or more difficult.
  In addition, there are other better way to do.
  Any ideas are inspiring!

Comment: Check this: http://community.opennetcf.com/forums/t/11143.aspx